# How to store array with the question and its specific answer in db in laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

How do I store an array of questions and answers in Laravel?

**For example**: The user is asked a question. The question has 3 answers. The user has to select 1 answer from the 3. I have to store the data of that specific user with that question and the selected answer.

I have two models (**Question** and **Answer**). The relationship is One-To-Many (Questions to Answers).

I want to store it like this:

```
[
    ['question1' => 'value', 'answer' => 'value'),
    ['question2' => 'value', 'answer' => 'value'),
]
```

```php
public function saveQuestion(Request $request) { 
// dd($request->all()); 
$exist = $request->user(); 
if(isset($exist)) { 
  $total_rows = $request->input('total_questions'); 
  $data = array(); 
  for($i = 0; $i < $total_rows; $i++){ 
    $qa = array( 
        'question' => $request->input('question'.$i), 
        'answer' => $request->input('answer'.$i)
    ); 
  } 
  if(isset($data) && $data!=''){ 
    return $this->outputJSON('Record Saved',200,$data);
  }
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far so that we know specifically what you're struggling with.

Comment: Please share your database schema or table structure? and as @shreif said what you have done. so we can understand your question, and anyone can give you a proper answer.

Comment: public function saveQuestion(Request $request)
    {
       // dd($request->all());
        $exist = $request->user();
        if(isset($exist)) {
            $total_rows = $request->input('total_questions');
            $data = array();
            for($i = 0; $i < $total_rows; $i++){
                $qa = array(
                    'question' => $request->input('question'.$i),
                    'answer' => $request->input('answer'.$i));
            }
            if(isset($data) && $data!=''){
                return $this->outputJSON('Record Saved',200,$data);}

Comment: now i want to post this data array into the model Personality_evaluation
which contains id(its own id), quesiton_id, answer_id , value